# Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 or later SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, submit, app-store-connect

Submit for Review in iTunesConnect returns:
"Apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1 or later, and iOS 7 or later SDK."

The thing is that:
- My build was made with Xcode 6.1
- Deployment Target is 7.0 as well

I Tried to submit it through Xcode and Application Loader.

Still, iTunesConnect keeps giving me same error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: As you use XCode 6.1, check you don't have your base SDK set to iOS 8.1. App submissions are not open for iOS 8.1.

Comment: My base SDK is set to "Latest iOS (iOS 8.0)"

Comment: I've discover that although Xcode 6.1 is GM you can not submit app with it. You will need to build them with Xcode 6

Comment: Do you mean Xcode 6.0.1?

Comment: Success, ty.
Worked with Xcode 6.0.1

Comment: @MarcusAdams Yes 6.0.1 will do.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. How downgrade the 6.1 to 6.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Although Xcode 6.1 is names GM it is not yet released and can't be used submit apps right now.

You can use Xcode 6 or 6.0.1